# What is a tool to sort apps by their data size?

Tags: internal-storage

During development, internal storage size is severely needed. Cache cleaner is ok, however, apps have another component called data which can be cleared. Is there an app out there that organizes by an app's data size ? I'm not interested in app size, I'm interested in app's data size.

Comment: You can already sort apps in the app manager by size. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Also, we prefer questions in the form "how can I do X" rather than "is there an app that does X". Apps come and go and there may be a non-app solution to your problem.

Comment: Im not interested in app size, i'm interested in app's data size. Google maps takes up lots of data. There are lots of apps with small size, but large data size...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You may wish to add that to your question so that you can get the most helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer's a bit late, but you haven't received a good one yet!

In [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), you can do Menu -> More -> Overview of app storage use, then order by data size. Not only will you have your apps sorted by data size, TI shows you the size with graphical bars, so you can compare apps at a glance and see what's huge vs. tiny. See the last screenshot on the market (the free version) for an example.

Another option: [App 2 SD by Sam Lu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd). Not as pretty, and the apps are split over 3 screens, but it is possible by doing Menu -> Sort by -> Data size.

Finally, if you have a rooted phone and an ext partition, you can move some or all of your data to the ext partition and gain tons of space!

Comment: Titanium backup looks good in theory, but it never finishes "building exact app size information" on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

**[1Tap Cleaner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.acc.free)** is capable of that, I use it all the time to clear data-hogging apps.

Once in the app choose **Cache Cleaner** then bring up the **Settings** > **Sort by Size** > **Data size**.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DiskUsage](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&feature=search_result).  It'll let you see what is consuming the most space on either internal or SD card.

Comment: Disk usage does not allow sorting by data components - what the author specifically asked for.

Comment: @Dmitry That's available through menu>filter or by browsing to a mount point.

Comment: seems to support SD cards only at least nowadays